# SqlKata - I'm not understanding how Paginate works

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqlkata

I am a beginner using this library SqlKata, and I'm having hard time understanding the functionality of the Paginate method.

With the Get method, I can access the SQL records. But with Paginate I can not. Will the Paginate method bring me the records of the database?

```
dim db = new QueryFactory(new SqlConnection("[connection-string]"), new SqlServerCompiler())
dim library = db.Query("my_table").Select("*").Paginate(1, 10)
for each book in library.each
    response.write(book.id)
next
```

This throws a error:

> Public member 'id' on type 'PaginationResult(Of Object)' not found.

System information:

> SqlKata 1.1.3
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3163.0
>
> VB.NET

Comment: What is the content of query `my_table`, `id` may not selected in your query.

Comment: @Aria I selected all columns as you can see with `db.Query("my_table").Select("*")`. If I use `db.Query("my_table").Get() I can get the id. I think it's not a problem with the Query but a problem with how to handle this PaginationResult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the documentation needs an update.

Here's how I managed to use the pagination:

```vb
dim db = new QueryFactory(new SqlConnection("[connection-string]"), new SqlServerCompiler())

dim q = db.Query("my_table")

'Just if you need to know total of pages and other utilities
dim info = q.Paginate(1, 10)

'DB rows
for each book in info.list
    response.write(book.id)
next

'If you do not need the pagination object, you can use:

'here we retrieve 10 records from page 2
for each book in q.ForPage(2, 10).Get()
    response.write(book.id)
next
```